# Grid View text dissapear on scroll in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I am making a gridview which displaying the Images using Image Loader concept from gallery. In grid view item there are two views one is Image and other is textview. By default textview is not visible. My need is when i click on gridview item then textview should be visible which will show the number of clicks on particular item of grid. But problem is when i click on grid item then Textview showing click count, but when scrolling the grid view the textview get dissapeared. I am stucking on this since two days, please help me to solve problem.

Here is my GetView Method;

```
        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
         View view;

         ArrayList<String> mList;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        Context mContext;



    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        mList = new ArrayList<String>();

        this.mList = imageList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    view=convertView;           
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_multiphoto_item, null);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final TextView click_count=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.count);
    imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + imageUrls.get(position), imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ImageGridActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
            imageView.setAnimation(anim);
            anim.start();
        }
    });

    // click_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        int c=0;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            image_url.add(imageUrls.get(position));
            count.setText("("+image_url.size()+")");
            c=c+1;
            click_count.setTag(view);
            click_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            click_count.setText(String.valueOf(c));
            count.setText("("+image_url.size()+")");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cuy;;; "+position, 89).show();
        }
    });
//}
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: do u know javabeen like pojo class in java i have done this work

Comment: Use viewHolder like class for holding your views..

Comment: can you please post whole adapter code ?

Comment: @Gunaseelan , Can you explain how to use view holder here. I have used it but was not helpful, may be I was doing wrong. I think its only cause of ViewHolder. Please help me if you can. Thanks.

Comment: @HareshChhelana , ok Iam posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
    private Animation anim;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageList){
        this.context = context;
        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (String image : imageList){
            HashMap<String,String> row =  new HashMap<String, String>();
            row.put("image",image);
            row.put("count","0");
            list.add(row);
        }
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder =new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_multiphoto_item, null);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.click_count = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.imageView.setAnimation(anim);
        imageLoader.displayImage("file://"+list.get(position).get("image").toString(), holder.imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                anim.start();
            }
        });
        holder.click_count.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).get("count")));
        if(list.get(position).get("count").equals("0")){
            holder.click_count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            holder.click_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                list.get(position).put("count",String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).get("count"))+1));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView click_count;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I try , but click_count is not showing text(count).

Comment: is click_count text is not visible ? and please check i have edited my ans.

Comment: not visible if i set visibility.VISIBLE then SetTxt() is not setting text to textview.

Comment: it is showing text but problem is not showing on same at which I am clicking. If I am clicking on 1st item then text will show on 15th position  or may vary

Comment: application crashed on using this code.  error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to com.img.rempic.ImageGridActivity$ImageAdapter3$ViewHolder

Comment: Crash is resolved now and Click_count is showing count value but it disappeared while scrolling.